# How to separate elements of a line having multiple delimiters via Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file, export-to-csv

```
date Mon Jan 4 15:59:21.129 2021

base hex  timestamps absolute

no internal events logged

// version 13.0.0

//545285.973861 previous log file: Myfile_0.asc

// Measurement UUID: 4520e127-a0b6-48d2-9e23-2588160af285

545333.620639 LoggingString := "Log,11:28 PM, Sunday, January 10, 2021,11:28:17.4,34.72,12,0.01058,11.99,0.01077,12,0.01127,11.99,0.01142,11.76,0.1053,11.99,0.01076,11.96,0.01092,2.516,0,2,OM_2_1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

545335.691676 LoggingString := "Log,11:28 PM, Sunday, January 10, 2021,11:28:19.5,34.61,12,0.01058,11.99,0.01072,11.99,0.01127,11.99,0.01139,11.87,0.1118,12.01,0.01046,11.99,0.01145,2.581,0,2,OM_2_1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

545337.796715 LoggingString := "Log,11:28 PM, Sunday, January 10, 2021,11:28:21.6,34.52,11.99,0.0106,11.99,0.01077,11.99,0.01151,11.99,0.01139,11.72,0.1081,12,0.0109,11.96,0.01107,2.543,0,2,OM_2_1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

545339.919752 LoggingString := "Log,11:28 PM, Sunday, January 10, 2021,11:28:23.7,34.41,12,0.01082,11.99,0.01104,11.99,0.01156,11.99,0.01164,11.62,0.1042,11.99,0.01105,11.96,0.01126,2.596,0,2,OM_2_1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
```

The above text represents my input data from a log file (below available in image format too) :

I want to perform certain operations with the data shown in the image. However, i am unable to figure out a method to split each element in the line.
The data starting after 11:28:17.4 is of importance for me . I have used the  **numpy.genfromtxt** function  & **usecols** arg to print data between columns 6 and 22..however, i wanted to be able to split each element of the row so that i could use the elements as identifiers to begin recording the important data for me.

For e.g in line 7, there is "whitespace, comma" as separators. How do i split the data so that at the end i get the following as output :

**List = ['545333.620639','Logging String:=', 'Log', .........., 2021, 11:28:17.4, 34.72 .....]**

Also, when i use "Readlines()", is the data stored as one complete string in the List or as individual string elements in List?

This is a more hardcoded approach to the solution i want. This gives me a .csv file at the end with specific data extracted from a larger dataset.. However, i want a better approach to this.

1. Instead of manually defining line number as counter to start storing data into .csv, i want to be able to define that if "// Measurement UUID:" is detected, then start  storing data into .csv from next line
2. To be able to separate each line into individual elements
3. How to define multipe delimiters for "np.genfromtxt" function

```
import numpy as np

Testfile = open('C:/Documents/Myfile.asc','r')
Read_data = Testfile.readlines()
count = 0
for line in Read_data:
     count += 1
     if count < 7:        ## counter to start saving data into .csv from 7th line
         print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
     else:
         mydat = np.genfromtxt("C:/Documents/Myfile.asc",skip_header=(count-1),usecols=   (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23),delimiter=',')
         Data_frame = pd.DataFrame(mydat)
         Data_frame.to_csv("Triall_3.csv",sep=';')
         exit()
```

[image]

Comment: You could just ignore the header information and then read the file line by line. Then using the ste split() method. This will generate a list - and since the list will always have the same amount of elements you can use normal python indexing to discard the not needed information in front

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there input data as text (so we can copy and paste-it)?

Comment: @AndrejKesely i made the changes as per your request

Comment: @Chris how is it possible to ignore the header information ( first 6 lines) of the file while reading the file using readlines() in python? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question well. You can check if there's `LoggingString :=` inside the line and if is, split the string:

```py
import pandas as pd

out = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if "LoggingString :=" in line:
            first_quote = line.index('"')
            last_quote = line.index('"', first_quote + 1)
            out.append(
                line[:first_quote].split(maxsplit=1)
                + line[first_quote + 1 : last_quote].split(","),
            )

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              0                  1    2         3        4            5      6           7      8      9        10     11       12     13       14     15       16     17      18     19       20     21       22     23 24 25      26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
0  545333.620639  LoggingString :=   Log  11:28 PM   Sunday   January 10   2021  11:28:17.4  34.72     12  0.01058  11.99  0.01077     12  0.01127  11.99  0.01142  11.76  0.1053  11.99  0.01076  11.96  0.01092  2.516  0  2  OM_2_1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  545335.691676  LoggingString :=   Log  11:28 PM   Sunday   January 10   2021  11:28:19.5  34.61     12  0.01058  11.99  0.01072  11.99  0.01127  11.99  0.01139  11.87  0.1118  12.01  0.01046  11.99  0.01145  2.581  0  2  OM_2_1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  545337.796715  LoggingString :=   Log  11:28 PM   Sunday   January 10   2021  11:28:21.6  34.52  11.99   0.0106  11.99  0.01077  11.99  0.01151  11.99  0.01139  11.72  0.1081     12   0.0109  11.96  0.01107  2.543  0  2  OM_2_1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  545339.919752  LoggingString :=   Log  11:28 PM   Sunday   January 10   2021  11:28:23.7  34.41     12  0.01082  11.99  0.01104  11.99  0.01156  11.99  0.01164  11.62  0.1042  11.99  0.01105  11.96  0.01126  2.596  0  2  OM_2_1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej. It worked out as i wanted. Thank you specifically for pointing out the "Loggingstring:=" aspect.... really helped reducing the complexity of my approach here . Have a great day :)

Comment: one more question to you. This method generates a List of lists if i'm not wrong. I used out[x][y] to access the values of individual elements of this list of lists... however, they are in string format.. if i want them as float for mathematical analysis purpose how do i do that? map(float,Out[x][y]) returns ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'     ........ If you could help me out, it'd be really grateful

Comment: @SajeevPillai It would be better to open a new question here on StackOverflow where you describe the issue. I'd try to look at it...

Comment: i just posted a new post with details. Thank you